# Power BI - Column Value being converted to lower case

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-databricks

I have a data source coming in from Azure Data Bricks and I am using the Azure Data Bricks Connector in Power BI . There is a column called Reference Number and values like PERT is coming in as pert . Lower case instead of upper case - it does not seem to be happening for all values like AD435 comes in ok. Field is ABC text in Power BI and it is string in Azure Data Bricks.

IN Azure Data Bricks it is PERT and not pert . If I bring in 1 record instead of all records in the table it comes in as PERT and not pert, which is bizarre . Anyone else having this issues in Power BI when bringing in tables from Azure Data Bricks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential problem with Power BI Azure Data Bricks connector as I cannot logically explain this . Worked round it by bringing these records in a separate table in Power BI Data Model.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer I know.

Power BI is case-insensitive after the data leaves Power Query.  The way it seems to achieve this is to use the first value it finds and then all further values that would match an upper(text) = upper(text) type match then use the case of that first string.

I encountered this trying to join two tables in a model.  In my case I had trouble defining the join due to "Duplicates" in the One side of the One to Many.